# How do you *get* the number of threads for BLAS operations in Julia?

Tags: julia

Julia's blas library has a function `set_num_threads()` which sets the threads for BLAS operations.

How do I **get** the number of threads being used by default, or currently?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have your Julia linked against OpenBLAS, which would be the case if you use the Windows, Mac or generic Linux binaries from julialang.org, or if you build from source and don't set `USE_SYSTEM_BLAS=1`, then you get the number threads used by OpenBLAS by calling `ccall((:openblas_get_num_threads64_, Base.libblas_name), Cint, ())`. Eventually, we'll probably provide this as a Julia function.

Comment: See https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/251a501def6a52d497784ad1ca8206579d814bce/stdlib/Distributed/test/distributed_exec.jl#L918 (note that one must change `LinearAlgebra` to `LinAlg` for julia versions < 0.7.

Comment: Now `BLAS.get_num_threads()` does the trick. Maybe an update would be welcome.

Answer (score 7):

As of Julia 1.6, you can use `LinearAlgebra.BLAS.get_num_threads()`. So the following code will do the trick:

```
using LinearAlgebra
BLAS.get_num_threads()
```

Answer (score 4):

`Module BLAS` in Julia `Base` is a wrapper of blas library which can be `openblas`, `mkl` etc.

By default, OpenBLAS use one thread for small matrices and [multi-thread](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS#set-the-number-of-threads-with-environment-variables) you set in enviriment variables for large matrices.

> Set the number of threads with environment variables.
>
> Examples:
>
> export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4
>   or
>
> export GOTO_NUM_THREADS=4
>   or
>
> export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
>   The priorities are OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS > GOTO_NUM_THREADS > OMP_NUM_THREADS.
>
> If you compile this lib with USE_OPENMP=1, you should set OMP_NUM_THREADS >environment variable. OpenBLAS ignores OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS and >GOTO_NUM_THREADS with USE_OPENMP=1.

MKL can automatically tune the number of threads for different size of matrices.

---

You can use global const dict variable `ENV` in Julia to get environment variables. But the number of threads you are using will be different when you set it on runtime or set it larger than the cores available in your machine.

If you use the Apple provided BLAS in `vecLi`, you can via `ENV["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"]` to get the number of threads you are using whether you set the number of threads with environment variables or set it on runtime.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question...?

Comment: I think OP is asking *how* to set the environment variables you reference in your answer.